# Initialize UIViewController with code gives black screen

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am trying to build an app entirely with coding and no storyboard usage. I am trying to use Coordinater pattern here. I am trying to set my initial controller with my view model in init method but I am getting only a black screen. Although the init and viewDidLoad code is executed but the screen still remains black. Following is my Coordinator:

```
    class AppCoordinator {
    private let window: UIWindow
    
    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
    }
    
    func start() {
        let viewController = ViewController(with: RestaurantListViewModel(restaurantService: RestaurantService()))
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private var viewModel: RestaurantListViewModel!
    
    init(with viewModel: RestaurantListViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }

        public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.viewModel = nil
        }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        let service = RestaurantService()
        service.fetchRestaurants().subscribe { restaurants in
            print(restaurants)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate:

```
    class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appCoordinator: AppCoordinator?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        
        appCoordinator = AppCoordinator(window: window)
        appCoordinator?.start()
    }
}
```

**Edit1:**

[image: info.plist]

Comment: One possibility is that your app is starting from Storybord. Please check that first.

Comment: I have already removed storyboard

Comment: Is viewDidLoad being called?

Comment: Could you please attach your AppDelegate code? Also, check if you still have the "Scene Configuration" entry in your Info.plist. You might have deleted it entirely to fix a crash while you only need to delete a "Storyboard Name" property from the default scene configuration.

Comment: @Asteroid yes viewDidLoad is being called.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev AppDelegate has no changes, I have not touched it. I have also attached a screenshot of info.plist. It has Scene Configuration

Comment: If viewDidLoad is being called, can you try changing the color in viewDidAppear? Also, try to set the modalPresentation mode of your vc to fullScreen.

Comment: It appears that you've done the basic setup correctly. The only thing that I'd try is to store the reference to the main window in the SceneDelegate's `window` property because this property is one of the requirements of the `UIWindowSceneDelegate` protocol, but in my experiments it worked even without that. Can it be something in your view controller's code that renders it black? Have you provided the full source code of the view controller or is it just an excerpt?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev - that's the right answer. From testing, I reproduced the same issue when the window instance wasn't assigned. I suspect the difference may lie when a storyboard is used vs manually managed window.

Comment: @Panks - It does not look like there is anything wrong with your code or setup... I just created a new project using your code, and it works fine (I'm passing a color in init, since I don't have your view model or `DisposeBag` code). Have you tried deleting the app from the simulator / device and running it again?

Comment: Not sure what was the prob here, the same code is working now, I did delete the app and Derived Data a few times though